# `conda install pytorch` results in 'Illegal instruction' with `import torch`

Tags: installation, pytorch, conda

With a fresh install of anaconda, followed by `conda install pytorch`, I get an `Illegal instruction` (crashing the python interpreter) whenever I `import torch`:

```
(base) ~$ python -c 'import torch'
Illegal instruction
(base) 132 ~$
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case is that it's a CPU machine and thus doesn't have CUDA installed. In this case you need to install `pytorch-cpu` instead:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch-cpu
```

After that, it works fine.

(Thanks to [@JuanFMontesinos on the pytorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/installing-pytorch-without-a-gpu/22455/2?u=drevicko))